How to retrieve total token supply (circulating minted tokens) within a Solana program?
I'm developing a Solana program using the Anchor framework. In one of my instructions, I need to fetch the total number of minted tokens currently in circulation. I'm aware that this information can be obtained via the getTokenSupply() RPC call.
However, I'd like to know if it's possible to achieve this directly within the Solana program itself.

every mint carries its total supply as part of its account data. in the normal spl_token crate, spl_token::state::Mint is defined as such:
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Mint {
    pub mint_authority: COption<Pubkey>,
    pub supply: u64,
    pub decimals: u8,
    pub is_initialized: bool,
    pub freeze_authority: COption<Pubkey>,
}

and supply is the total amount of tokens
anchor seems to provide an opaque wrapper, anchor_spl::token::Mint, on the spl type. it isnt clear to me how you use it to access the underlying type (perhaps anchor automatically deserializes it in the accounts struct?) but thats where you want to look

try ctx.accounts.your_token_mint.supply may be ? I think anchor deserializes automatically like accounts from your program
